# phpMyAdmin error 1136 message

Tags: phpmyadmin

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code

```
--
-- Database: `mydb1931`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Former Cast`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Former Cast` (
  `Character` varchar(100),
  `Actor(s)` varchar(100),
  `Duration` varchar(100),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I keep receiving this error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 15
```

UPDATE

Ok I fixed the rest of the 1064 errors and got a few more errors, now I'm getting one that reads

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 11
```

here is my entire code

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.9.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: March 04, 2015 at 15:00
-- Server version: 5.6.22-log
-- PHP Version: 5.5.15-pl0-gentoo

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb1931`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Former Cast`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Former Cast` (
  `Character` varchar(100),
  `Actor(s)` varchar(100),
  `Duration` varchar(100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Former Cast`
--

INSERT INTO `Former Cast` (`character`, `actor(s)`, `duration`) VALUES
('Finn O Connor', 'Keith Rice', '2010-11, 2013-15'),
('Will Savage', 'James Atherton', '2011–15'),
('Dodger Savage', 'Danny Mac', '2011–15'),
('Sandy Roscoe', 'Gillian Taylforth', '2013–15'),
('Rick Spencer', 'Victor Gardener', '2014–15'),
('Amy Barnes', 'Ashley Slanina-Davies', '2005–14'),
('Terry Hay', 'Conor Ryan', '2007–08, 2014'),
('Shane', 'Jody Latham', '2014'),
('Dennis Savage', 'Joe Tracini', '2011–14'),
('Blessing Chambers', 'Modupe Adeyeye', '2014'),
('Carmel Valentine', 'Gemma Merna' '2006–14'),
('Sonny Valentine', 'Devon Anderson', NULL),
(NULL, 'Aaron Fontaine', '2006–07, 2014'),
('Big Bob', 'Vincent Ebrahim',  '2014'),
('Kathleen McQueen', 'Alison Burrows', '2009-11, 2014'),
('George Smith', 'Steven Roberts', '2011–14'),
('Vincent Elegba', 'John Omole', '2013–14'),
('Amber Sharpe', 'Lydia Lloyd-Henry', NULL),
(NULL, 'Lauren Gabrielle-Thomas', '2010, 2014'),
('Bella Sharpe', 'Imaani Byndloss', '2013–14'),
('Rhys Ashworth', 'Andrew Moss', '2005–12, 2014'),
('Sam Lomax', 'Lizzie Roper', '2013–14'),
('Danny Lomax', 'Stephen Billington', '2013–14'),
('Fraser Black', 'Jesse Birdsall', '2013–14'),
('Alex Browning', 'Ojan Genc', '2014'),
('Superintendent Marlow', 'Paul Clayton', '2013–14'),
('Katy O Connor', 'Uncredited', '2013–14'),
('Ruby Button', 'Anna Shaffer', '2011–14'),
('Jim McGinn', 'Dan Tetsell', '2012–14'),
('Chloe Chance', 'Susan Loughnane', '2013–14'),
('Tilly Evans', 'Lucy Dixon', '2011–14'),
('Mel', 'Emma Rydal', '2012, 2013'),
('Martha Kane', 'Carli Norris', '2012-13'),
('Leanne Holiday',  'Jessica Forrest',  '2010–13'),
('Ash Kane', 'Holly Weston', '2011–'),
('Doug Carter', 'PJ Brennan', '2010–13'),
('Doctor Browning', 'Joseph Thompson',  '2012–13'),
('Clare Devine', 'Samantha Rowley', '2005–07'),
(NULL, 'Gemma Bissix', '2009, 2013'),
('Callum Kane', 'Laurie Duncan', '2011–13'),
('Kevin Foster', 'Elliot Balchin', '2013'),
('Jade Hedy', 'Lucy Gape', '2013'),
('Anna Blake', 'Saskia Wickham', '2013'),
('Pauline Hay', 'Jane Hogarth', '2008, 2009, 2012, 2013'),
('Richie Trent', 'Michael Dixon', '2013'),
('Liberty Savage', 'Abi Phillips', '2010–13'),
('Lynsey Nolan', 'Karen Hassan', '2008, 2010–12, 2013'),
('Barney Harper-McBride', 'Tom Scurr', '2011–13'),
('Texas Longford', 'Bianca Hendrickse-Spendlove', '2010–13'),
('Jacqui McQueen', 'Claire Cooper', '2006–13'),
('Trudy Ryan', 'Danniella Westbrook', '2013'),
('Rob O Connor', 'Gary Cargill', '2010–11, 2013'),
('Liam Gilmore', 'James Farrar', '2012–13'),
('Jen Gilmore', 'Amy Downham', '2012–13'),
('Nate Tenbury-Newent', 'Tom Turner', '2013'),
('Cheryl Brady', 'Bronagh Waugh', '2008, 2009–13'),
('Seamus Brady', 'Fintan McKeown', '2012–13'),
('Simon Walker', 'Neil Newbon', '2012, 2013'),
('Dylan Shaw' 'Mikey Riddington-Smith', '2012–13'),
('Annalise Appleton', 'Tamaryn Payne', '2011–13'),
('Rob Edwards', 'David Atkins', '2011–13'),
('Mitzeee Minniver', 'Rachel Shenton', '2010–13'),
('Carl Costello', 'Paul Opacic', '2010–11, 2012, 2013'),
('Bobby McQueen', 'Jacob', '2011–12, 2013'),
('Mr Keeler', 'Carl Cieka', '2012–13'),
('Bart McQueen', 'Jonny Clarke', '2010–13'),
('Joel Dexter', 'Andrew Still', '2011–13'),
('Declan Brady', 'Jay Duffy', '2011–12'),
('Suzanne Ashworth', 'Suzanne Hall', '2005–10, 2011, 2012'),
('Lacey Kane', 'Georgia Bourke', '2012'),
('Ally Gorman', 'Dan O Connor', '2012'),
('Martin Jono Johnson', 'Dylan Llewellyn', '2011–12'),
('Maddie Morrison', 'Scarlett Bowman', '2011–12'),
('Neil Cooper', 'Tosin Cole', '2011–12'),
('Eoghan Nolan', 'Alan Turkington', '2012'),
('Riley Costello', 'Rob Norbury', '2010–12'),
('Trish Minniver', 'Paula Wolfenden', '2010–11, 2012'),
('Ricky Campbell', 'Ashley Margolis', '2009–12'),
('Michaela McQueen', 'Hollie-Jay Bowes', '2006–10, 2011–12'),
('Josh Ashworth', 'Sonny Flood', '2005–10, 2012'),
('Ryan', 'George Evans', '2012'),
('DI Small', 'Victoria Pritchard', '2011, 2012'),
('Sampson', 'Sean Cernow',  '2012'),
('Scott Sabeka', 'Calvin Demba', '2011–12'),
('Silas Blissett', 'Jeff Rawle', '2010–11, 2012'),
('Ed Morrison', 'Dominic Rickhards', '2012'),
('India Longford', 'Beth Kingston', '2009–10, 2011, 2012'),
('Laurence Saywood', 'As Himself', '2011–12'),
('Louis Souyave', 'As Himself', '2011–12'),
('Danny Lawrence', 'As Himself', '2011–12'),
('Sam Fordham', 'As Himself', '2011–12'),
('Matt Gill', 'As Himself', '2011–12'),
('Wardy', 'Karl James Wilson', '2012'),
('Jodie Wilde', 'Montana Manning', '2011–12'),
('Deena Hardman', 'Sian Breckin', '2012'),
('Graham Hardman', 'Steve Marsh', '2012'),
('Margaret Hayton', 'Darryl Fishwick', '2005, 2006, 2007, 2012'),
('Seth Costello',   'Miles Higson', '2010–11'),
('Steph Cunningham',    'Carley Stenson',   '2000–10, 2011'),
('Rebecca "Jenny" Massey',  'Daisy Turner', '2011'),
('Warren Fox',  'Jamie Lomas',  '2006–09, 2010–11'),
('Ethan Scott', 'Craig Vye',    '2010–11'),
('Jason Costello', 'Victoria Atkin',    '2010–11'),
('Gilly Roach', 'Anthony Quinlan',  '2005–11'),
('Gaz Bennett', 'Joel Goonan', '2008–10, 2011'),
('Duncan Button', 'Dean Aspen', '2009–11'),
('Kelly Saunders', 'Danielle Malone', '2011'),
('Heidi Costello',  'Kim Tiddy',    '2010–11'),
('Lee Hunter',  'Alex Carter',  '2001–05, 2010–11'),
('Father Francis',  'Richard Windsor',  '2011'),
('Mandy Richardson',    'Sarah Jayne Dunn', '1996–2006, 2007, 2008, 2010–  11'),
('Rae Wilson',  'Alice Barlow', '2009–11'),
('Jamil Fadel', 'Sikander Malik',   '2010–11'),
('Pete Hamill', 'Peter Mitchell', '2011'),
('Noah Baxter', 'Law Thompson', '2011'),
('William Alexander', 'Richard Graham', '2011'),
('Emily Alexander', 'Elizabeth Henstridge', '2011'),
('Francine Osborne',    'Lexi', '2011'),
('Jack Osborne',    'Reuben',   '2011'),
('Calvin Valentine',    'Ricky Whittle',    '2006–10, 2011'),
('Kyle Ryder',  'Neil Toon',    '2010, 2011'),
('Melody Longford', 'Sandy Hendrickse', '2010–11'),
('Anita Roy',   'Saira Choudhry',   '2008–11'),
('Eva Strong',  'Sheree Murphy',    '2010–11'),
('David "Bombhead" Burke',  'Lee Otway',    '2001–05, 2010, 2011'),
('Fern',    'Amy Gavin',    '2010–11'),
('Trev Costello',   'Scott Neal',   '2010'),
('Danny Houston',   'Darren Day',   '2010'),
('Gabby Sharpe',    'Phina Oruche', '2010'),
('Taylor Sharpe',   'Shaun Blackstock', '2010'),
('Arlo Davenport',  'Travis Yates', '2010'),
('Liam McAllister', 'Chris Overton',    '2010'),
('Jem Costello',    'Helen Russell-Clark',  '2010'),
('Dominic Reilly',  'John Pickard', '2005–10'),
('Ravi Roy',    'Stephen Uppal',    '2008–10'),
('Erin Fisher', 'Gemma Craven', '2008, 2009, 2010'),
('Malachy Fisher',  'Glen Wallace', '2007, 2008–10'),
('Kris Fisher', 'Gerard McCarthy',  '2006–10'),
('Phil Sharpe', 'Andonis Anthony',  '2010'),
('Elliot Bevan',    'Garnon Davies',    '2007–10'),
('Kevin Smith', 'Cameron Crighton', '2010'),
('Alistair Longford',   'Terence Harvey',   '2010'),
('Charlotte Lau',   'Amy Yamazaki', '2009–10'),
('Dave Colburn',    'Elliot James Langridge',   '2009–10'),
('Leo Valentine',   'Brian Bovell', '2006–10'),
('Lauren Valentine',    'Dominique Jackson',    '2007–10'),
('Sasha Valentine', 'Nathalie Emmanuel',    '2006–10'),
('Spencer Gray',    'Darren John Langford', '2008–10'),
('Valerie Holden',  'Jacqueline Leonard', '2007, 2008,'),
(NULL, 'Samantha Giles',     '2010'),
('Zak Ramsey',  'Kent Riley',   '2004–05, 2006–10'),
('Jake Dean',   'Kevin Sacre',  '2002–08, 2009–10'),
('Des Townsend', 'Kris Deedigan',   '2009–10'),
('Rose Townsend', 'Libby Davison',  '2010'),
('Tariq Mistry', 'Rudi Dharmalingham',  '2010'),
('Meriel Vaughn',   'Emily Corselli',   '2010'),
('Loretta Jones',   'Melissa Walton',   '2008, 2009–10'),
('Adam',    'Vlach Ashton', '2010'),
('Neville Ashworth',    'Jim Millea',   '2005–10'),
('Barry Newton',    'Nico Mirallegro',  '2007–10'),
('Shelly Newton',   'Beverly Denim',    '2008, 2010'),
('Kenzie',  'Michael Taylor',   '2010'),
('Olly Larkin', 'Oliver Watton',    '2010'),
('Archie Carpenter',    'Stephen Beard',    '2008–10'),
('Eddie Griffiths', 'Che Watson',   '2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010'),
('Sheila Buxton',   'Jessica Hall', '2009–10'),
('Hayley Ramsey',   'Kelly-Marie Stewart',  '2009–10'),
('Hannah Ashworth', 'Emma Rigby',   '2005–10'),
('Jamie',   'Finn Jones',   '2009, 2010'),
('Zoe Carpenter',   'Zoë Lister',   '2006–10'),
('Mike Barnes', 'Tony Hirst',   '2006–10'),
('Fernando Fernandez',  'Jeronimo Best',    '2009–10'),
('Leila Roy',   'Lena Kaur',    '2008–10'),
('D.I. Fletcher',   'Laura Fletcher',   '2009–10'),
('Lydia Hart',  'Lydia Kelly',  '2009–10');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Indexes for table `Former Cast`
--
ALTER TABLE `Former Cast`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Character`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Does anyone know what this error means and how I can fix it??

Comment: Remove the last `,`at the end of `Duration`

Comment: o thanks it worked :) got another error now though haha

Comment: What's the error now?